# xsl multiple sort hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML structure which looks like this -

```
<Root>
  <name rank = "1">ABC
     <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
  </name>
  <name rank ="0">XYZ
     <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
     <name rank ="3">YYZ</name>
     <name rank ="0">FEG</name>
     <name rank ="0">DEG</name>         
  </name>
</Root>
```

I want to transform this XML by making a copy of it, preserving the hierarchy, and sort it in the order
(1) By Rank (ascending)
(2) If Ranks are equal, sort it by name(ascending)

After transformation, the structure should look like this.

```
<Root>      
      <name rank ="0">XYZ
         <name rank ="0">DEG</name>
         <name rank ="0">FEG</name>
         <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
         <name rank ="3">YYZ</name>         
      </name>
      <name rank = "1">ABC
         <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
      </name>
 </Root>
```

I have the following XSL, which does not preserve the heirarchy or gives me the correct sort. Can someone please help me out? This is my first time working with XSL and would appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

```
<xsl:template match="/*">

    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="//name">
        <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="name" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is no "DEG" string in the provided XML document. Also, `<name rank ="0">XYZ` -- this has only three children, but in the result the number of children is four. ???  Please, edit and correct.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>
     <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <name rank="{@rank}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>
     <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
  <name rank = "1">ABC
     <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
  </name>
  <name rank ="0">XYZ
     <name rank ="1">BCD</name>
     <name rank ="3">YYZ</name>
     <name rank ="0">FEG</name>
     <name rank ="0">DEG</name>
  </name>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Root>
    <name rank="0">XYZ
        <name rank="0">DEG</name>
        <name rank="0">FEG</name>
        <name rank="1">BCD</name>
        <name rank="3">YYZ</name></name>
    <name rank="1">ABC
        <name rank="1">BCD</name></name>
</Root>
```

**Explanation**:

Using two `xsl:sort` instructions. The priority of the sort operations corresponds to the document order of the respective `xsl:sort` instructions.

Comment: - Awesome! Thank you very much. I have a follow up question. In my case, the <Root> element will not be <Root> all the time (could be Root1,Root2 etc.) Is it possible to copy the entire document as it is and then apply the sort?

Comment: No need for two-passes. just use: `xsl:copy` instead of `Root`