# XSLT sort edge case for ascending sort by element name

Tags: xslt

This is a follow up to [question]: [xsl multiple sort hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829642/xsl-multiple-sort-heirarchy)

The XSL being used is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>
     <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <name rank="{@rank}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>   
     <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I have a case where the ranks are same, but the sort by element name (ASC) is incorrect.

```
<name rank="100000">Motor Sports
   <name rank="100000">Motorcycle Racing [MOCY]
      <name rank="100000">Motocross [MOCR]</name>
      <name rank="100000">Speedway [SPEE]</name></name>
   <name rank="100000">Motor Racing [MORA]
      <name rank="100000">Formula 1 [FO1]</name>
   </name>
</name>
```

In this case, "Motor Racing" should have been above "Motorcycle Racing". Can you guys help me figure this out?
I have tried adding both

```
<xsl:sort select="text()" order="ascending"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:sort select="name" order="ascending"/>
```

after

```
<xsl:sort select="text()" order="ascending"/>
```

However, that has not worked.

ANSWER:
Thanks to @MichaelKay for the answer, the way I resolved this was to change the XSLT processor to Saxon and use default-collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?decomposition=full"

Comment: Why've you got an empty `<xsl:sort/>` below each actual sort?

Comment: @MattGibson that seems to come from @DimitreNovatchev's answer to the previous question.  The secondary sort is supposed to be by the text value of the `<name>` node, which is what `<xsl:sort/>` should do (it's equivalent to `<xsl:sort select="."/>`).  But the XSLT spec is deliberately vague about how `data-type="text"` sorting is defined, it just says "lexicographically in the culturally correct manner for the language" so it's probably up to each processor whether it considers `"Motorc"` to be before or after `"Motor "`.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can specify `collation="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint"` on the `<xsl:sort>` to force it to use a non-language-specific ordering based on Unicode code points (i.e. U+0020 space would definitely be less than U+0063 lower-case c) but that option isn't available in 1.0.

Comment: @IanRoberts I tried doing that by changing the xsl spec to 2.0 and specifying the collation, but that did not work.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue with Xalan. Found this bug entry: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-1240 Saxon sorts as you are expecting it to. You might consider using Saxon instead of the default Java processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> "Motor Racing" should have been above "Motorcycle Racing"

XSLT does not define detailed collation rules. This is probably a collation in which spaces are ignored. Some people collate that way, others don't. Check the documentation for your XSLT processor, there may be a way of influencing the collation it uses.

Alternatively, you may be able to get the desired effect using something like

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(xxx, ' ', '-')"/>
```

Comment: @MichaealKay I am using the javax.xml.transform as my XSLT processor. I tried looking for a way to influence the collation, but could not find anything specific.
I also tried using the translate function as suggested, but that did not work either. Not sure if I am doing this right.
`<xsl:sort select="translate(text(),' ','-')"/>`

Comment: If you're using Java then you can easily switch to Saxon, which implements XSLT 2.0 and has extensive collation support. (Note, javax.xml.transform is an interface, not a processor: there are a number of implementations of this interface, though only Xalan and Saxon are commonly seen today.)

Comment: Thanks! (apologies for the delay, the storm hit us hard). I tried using the Saxon processor,
 
tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);

This solved the issue in question, but exhibits weird behavior in other instance which looks exactly the same as above. For instance,

`<name rank="">Olympics Medals Tables [OLT]</name>
<name rank="">Olympics Medals [OLM]</name>`

whereas the opposite order is expected. This works fine with the Xalan processor.

Comment: Saxon's default collation is Unicode codepoint, which is fast but not smart. Setting lang="en" will immediately give you a smarter natural-language collation. There are then many options to refine it further.