# XSLT 2.0 sort using Saxon in Java

Tags: xslt, saxon

This is a follow up to [XSLT sort edge case for ascending sort by element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052896/xslt-sort-edge-case-for-ascending-sort-by-element-name)

I have managed to resolve most of the issues using the answer described in that question. However there is still a case where sorting does not work as expected.

This is my source XML -

```
<Sources>
   <name rank="">ABcoop / Jiji Commodities News (Japanese) !RSC!</name>
   <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury &amp; Company News (Japanese) !RSS!</name>
   <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury News (Japanese) !RS!</name>
   <name rank="">AB Corporate Finance News !RINVB!</name>
   <name rank="">AB Insider !RITV!</name>
</Sources>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
default-collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?decomposition=full">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>   
    <xsl:sort />     
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <name rank="{@rank}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>   
    <xsl:sort />     
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorted output (Incorrect):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Sources>
       <name rank="">ABcoop / Jiji Commodities News (Japanese) !RSC!</name>
       <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury &amp; Company News (Japanese) !RSS!</name>
       <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury News (Japanese) !RS!</name>
       <name rank="">AB Corporate Finance News !RINVB!</name>
       <name rank="">AB Insider !RITV!</name>
    </Sources>
```

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Sources>
           <name rank="">AB Corporate Finance News !RINVB!</name>
           <name rank="">AB Insider !RITV!</name>
           <name rank="">ABcoop / Jiji Commodities News (Japanese) !RSC!</name>
           <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury &amp; Company News (Japanese) !RSS!</name>
           <name rank="">ABcoop Treasury News (Japanese) !RS!</name>           
        </Sources>
```

Edit: Additional Info since a couple of answer suggested that i use the default collation (removing the default-collation attribute) or `collation = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint"` for the xsl:sort element.

However, the issue as was pointed out in the previous post, is that other elements in my source XML are not sorted correctly when using unicode codepoint as the collation URI.

For example,

```
<Sources>
<name>FX Buzz News Service !fxbuz!</name>
<name>French General News Service !fb!</name>
<name>French Money / Debt News Service !fg!</name>
</Sources>
```

is not correctly sorted with unicode codepoint collation. I am trying to find a solution which works for all cases.

Comment: If you want plain sorting by Unicode codepoints without regard to locale then you need the collation `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint`

Comment: @IanRoberts, this works for the above case, but fails the sort for other cases. e.g
`<name rank="">FX Buzz News Service !FXBUZ!</name> <name rank="">French Equities / Economic News Service !FA!</name>`

The above sort works correctly, with the decomposition=full argument for the saxon collation. Also, Saxon uses unicode codepoint as its default collation mechanism.
Is there anything similar to decomposition that I can use with your collation URI?

Comment: Just delete the `default-collation` attribute and you get the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting by the rank attribute, but this has the same value in every element.

Comment: that is the primary sort, the secondary sort is against the name element text.
`<xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>   
 <xsl:sort />`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding lang="en" to the xsl:sort to get "English" sorting instead of unicode codepoint sorting. It may not be exactly what you want, but it will probably be closer.